# Wordpress page layout

Tags: wordpress, themes

I want to show two column with a right bar filled with google adsense. How can i change the default one column layout of the page in wordpress theme?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to edit the functions.php file and then manually add the area and the new sidebar into the page in the area you wish to do it.

so lets say it is index.php

you will open the functions.php file and then add this code

Create the widgets and sidebar section in the admin

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
register_sidebar(array('name'=>'YOUR NEW SIDEBAR',
'before_widget' => '<div class="block">',
'after_widget' => '</div><div class="blockfooter"></div>',
'before_title' => '<h3>',
'after_title' => '</h3>',
));
```

You will then add this part to the page in the area you want it added. styled with Div and so on or however you need it done.

```
<?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar('YOUR NEW SIDEBAR')); ?>
```

Let me know id this helps